# Loading HTML5 Application Slow on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am writing an HTML5 browser application. My app is about 80Kb at the moment, including html file, js files, css, jquery, etc. About 9 files are downloaded.

The thing that confuses me is that I can load the application up in the stock browser on a IDEOS X5 and it takes 30 seconds to load.

I can load the same application up in the stock browser on a samsung S2 and it loads up in less than a second.

They are both loading the same amount of data from the same server, over the same wifi connection so why so much difference? One is a dual core phone, and one a single core phone, but I wouldn't expect that to affect it that much.

UPDATE:

It was suggested that different versions of Android could cause this problem, but the devices are running similar versions of Android,

```
Samsung - 2.3.4
IDEOS - 2.3.5
```

But could there be a bug in the IDEOS browser? Having said that I did notice that the same slow page loading occured in opera mobile on the IDEOS.

Comment: its often a big difference when things can be processed concurrently....and browsers usually have pretty multi threaded scheme

Comment: What's a big difference? Multicore?

Comment: ya, but just saw that its 30 seconds vs under 1 second...so that really shouldnt matter =P

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Are you saying that the difference is too great for it to be a multicore vs single core thing?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your running a different OS on the IDEOS X5, its default is Android 2.2. Whereas the SGS is on Android 2.3.7, soon to be 4.0.3.

I bet thats the problem. An outdated browser that doesn't have proper HTML5 handling.

Comment: I had some thoughts like that myself, but the IDEOS X5 is running 2.3.5. I installed the update. The Samsung is running 2.3.4. I'll update the question around your thoughts.